# Swift Cocoa Reopen Application from Menu

Tags: swift, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a cocoa app and I can get it to reopen from the icon in the tray with the following in my AppDelegate file:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
    if !flag {
        for window in sender.windows {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

but I am not sure how to attach this function to an NSMenuItem that I create in the XIB so that I can have the user either click the NSMenuItem to reopen it. Is there a simple way that I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to do the same as "Bring All to Front" in the Window menu of the Xcode App template? If not, create an action method which unhides all windows and call this action method from `applicationShouldHandleReopen`.